# Why does my value only remain in the array for one loop?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fill an array with countries, however when I do, it only remains in the array for one loop. Anyone know how to help?

My code:

```
let country = ['3',"2"];

//This.setState in here.
data: data.map(country => {
          const { name } = country;
          country[count] = name;
          alert(country[0]);
          count++;              
        })
```

At first, the alert comes up as "Afghanistan", however every time after that it says "undefined".

Comment: What is `data` value? Also, you are calling `country[0]` in each iteration, which is not understandable.

Comment: Just https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pomber/covid19/master/docs/timeseries.json

Comment: You are not returning anything in `map` callback function, so it create a new array with each element set to `undefined`. Use `forEach` to loop, `map` is used to create new array.

Comment: I am using forEach, however I am encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent provided a lot of info (where does the `count` variable come from for instance) i'll point you in a more debuggable way:

So you have several things not following the React way, you want to create an object with key (country name) and value number of occurrences in the state. For that you should:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: data.map((country) => ({ ...prevState.data, [country]: data[country] ? data[country]++ : 1 });
}));

// test if you have what you need:
console.alert(this.state.data[0]);
```

So to explain what I did:

- Map returns an array;
- You need to include the data that you previously build or you will overwrite the previous state data;
- You'll have the key/value (dictionary) that you need.

This would work also for the reverse (key being the number and the value being the country).

Hope this helps!